# Plesk 11 SQL Server DB Restore from Zip Fle

Tags: backups, plesk, sql-server

This is a feature i had in DotNetPanel which i guess i took for granted because now that I've moved to Plesk 11, I don't have it anymore, and boy does it hurt.

My database restore uploads have increased from around 2mb (for a specific site) to around 50mb uncompressed.  No big deal in first world nations with super fast internet, but try this over a shitty connection in GUatemala or Nicaragua, and you'll know my pain.

I'm wondering if anybody out there knows of any third-party apps that can help me?  Sure i can ftp a zip file, RDP to the server, unzip, then restore from there, but RDP is sometimes painfully slow or even unavailable from some of these connections i'm forced to use, so i need something web-based.

Thanks in advance
Greg